# How to groupby records based on two parameters using pandas in python

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

If I need to group by my records on their minimum value I do the following

```
df.sort_values(['price']).drop_duplicates(['SKU']).to_csv('Min_Prices.csv',sep=';',index=False)
```

and I get

```
    id  price   editor 
1   k1  8.0     ed2 
2   k3  10.0    ed1 
4   k2  10.5    ed1
```

But I have an additional column of availability like

```
    id  price  availability   editor
 1  k1  8.0    0              ed2
 2  k1  9.0    1              ed1
 3  k1  9.5    1              ed3
 4  k4  9.5    1              ed1
 5  k4  9.0    0              ed2
 6  k5  8.5    1              ed1
 7  k5  7.8    0              ed2
```

The expected should be

```
k1 9.0 ed1
k4 9.5 ed1
k5 8.5 ed1
```

So how can I get minimums of availability of value 1. Where can I insert the availability in the initial formula?

thank you

Comment: What is expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) or [`DataFrame.query`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html):

```
df1 = df[df['availability'] == 1].sort_values(['price']).drop_duplicates(['id'])
#alternative
#df1 = df.query('availability == 1').sort_values(['price']).drop_duplicates(['id'])

print (df1)
   id  price  availability editor
6  k5    8.5             1    ed1
2  k1    9.0             1    ed1
4  k4    9.5             1    ed1

df1.to_csv('Min_Prices.csv',sep=';',index=False)
```

Comment: @Evridiki - But if ned test it in pandas by print is better 2 lines.

Comment: I think you missed a ) at the end :)

Comment: @Evridiki - copy typo :) Thank you.

Comment: @Evridiki - Multiple tutorials are [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/getting_started/tutorials.html#tutorials), I like modern pandas.